# macro definition and testing error: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 9

Tags: macros, conditionals

I want to define a macro to add comment in a `.tex` file.  As shown in the following code, I want to comment any thing between `\begincomment` and `\endcomment`.  However, it doesn't work.  An error says "incomplete \iffalse".   If I write

```
   \iffalse xxx \fi
```

directly, then all things work exactly the way I want.  However, I think this code like `\iffalse xx \fi` is not so readable and it is better to give this sequence another name.  Something like

```
    \begincomment
    \endcomment
```

Anyone can help me? I know some package that realize the macro `\begin{comment}\end{comment}`, but it doesn't work in math mode.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\def\begincomment{\iffalse}
\def\endcomment{\fi}
\begin{document}

    ------------------

    \begincomment
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    \endcomment

    ------------------
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

after `\begincomment`  everything is skipped so `\endcomment` is not expanded to see the `\fi`

use

```
\let\ifcomment\iffalse
```

then you can use

```
\ifcomment

commented out stuff

\fi
```

Comment: Is there any way to close a 'if' statement without explicitly using 'fi' ？ I means in any way to do this thing.  For example, rename the command 'fi' to something else

Comment: @gaoqiang you can use `\let\wibble=\fi` then use `\wibble` but I'd advise against it. As you saw `\if...\fi` matching is different to normal tex group matching and has its own scanning rules that allow correctly nesting `\if...\fi` inside skipped sections, it is _much_ easier to understand what is happening if all the if..fi matching commands start `\ifxxx` and end `\fi`

Comment: Thank you very much!   Learned a lot!

Comment: Actually,  what I want is something that more readable to human, not more readable to the "lex program". I feel like that the `\if ... \fi` matching is not so readable for human, since  I don't know what the `\fi` close (I mean it takes a while).  If I work with another person to complete a single document, he/she may be confused  and  it's not friendly for my coworker.  A `\begincomment \endcomment` style is more readable for human.

Comment: @gaoqiang sure but when the human is looking at `\ifcomment zzzz \iffalse www \endcomment zzz  \fi` they may be confused and not realise that `\endcomment` is an alias for `\fi` and matches the `\iffalse` and the `\fi` matches the `\ifcomment`. It works but I'm not sure it is easier for humans to understand. Perhaps you would prefer the `comment` package and `\begin{comment}...\end{comment}`

Answer (score 3):

If the ignored text is balanced (i.e. it does not include `{}` or it includes them but only matching in pairs), then you can define

```
\long\def\begincomment #1\endcomment{}
```

All balanced text followed by `\begincomment` is read to the `#1` parameter. This reading is terminated when the token `\endcomment` is found. The macro expands to nothing and the `#1` parameter is simply forgotten.

Comment: Thank you very much!   Learned a lot!  I don't know whether it works in  complex context.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse), then you can define this as an environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{comment}{+b}{\iffalse #1\fi}{}

\begin{document}

  \begin{comment}
    This is a comment.
  \end{comment}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much！ That's exactly what I want.  I tried the verbatim  package, but it doesn't work well in complex contex, such as in math mode.